# Mongo restore filter is not working

Tags: mongodb, restore, mongodump, mongorestore

I dump my mongo database and i want to restore it using filter, I am doing the following steps

I am writing the following command

```
mongorestore -h mongo1.xxx.projects.xyz.biz --db xxx --collection photos  --filter '{"_id" : { "$in": [ObjectId("54614b85ec8d83183f368a0d"), ObjectId("542c3b7b91201b49132d16d0"), ObjectId("546cac1691201b7b5438cac8"),ObjectId("546cac96ec8d830a7b33bfc7"),ObjectId("546bfd14ec8d830a8ad63db3"),ObjectId("5487691aec8d837be8426106"),ObjectId("54513bbeec8d8308418ce8f2"),ObjectId("545139b791201b63b43cb135"),ObjectId("549ca49891201b6562012d42"),ObjectId("54a32fdbec8d83019291d433"),ObjectId("54a42132ec8d83019bb5e23e"),ObjectId("54a423ce91201b64f73a9752"),ObjectId("54a42346ec8d83019291d444"),ObjectId("54a4246691201b64f73a9753"),ObjectId("54a425e3ec8d8301a1c3b85d"),ObjectId("54a4264291201b64f29d0db8"),ObjectId("54a4268fec8d8301a1c3b85e"),ObjectId("54a4275e91201b64f73a9755"),ObjectId("54a42e3f91201b64e8ed20d3"),ObjectId("54a42e6c91201b64e8ed20d4"),ObjectId("54a42e96ec8d8301a1c3b860"),ObjectId("54a43473ec8d83019bb5e253"),ObjectId("54a43c3a91201b64f29d0dc0"),ObjectId("54a43f05ec8d83019291d453"),ObjectId("54a43ff591201b64f29d0dc3"),ObjectId("54a4425c91201b64e8ed20dd"),ObjectId("54a442e1ec8d8301a1c3b866"),ObjectId("54a44767ec8d83019bb5e25c"),ObjectId("54a447daec8d8301a1c3b868"),ObjectId("54a450e291201b64f29d0dc9"),ObjectId("54a47e1a91201b64e8ed20e2"),ObjectId("54a48896ec8d83019bb5e26f"),ObjectId("54a48984ec8d830199f07151"),ObjectId("54a48b8c91201b64e8ed20ef"),ObjectId("54a493b1ec8d830199f07158"),ObjectId("54a495b3ec8d8301a1c3b89b"),ObjectId("54a73d11ec8d830199f0718b")]}}' /home/ubuntu/backup/05012015mongodump/dump/xxx/photos.bson
```

It says

```
2081 objects found
37 objects processed
```

But my data on mongo server is the same. Nothing restored

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. The notes on extended JSON in the manual should say use `{"$oid": "54614b85ec8d83183f368a0d"}` instead.

Comment: Thanks but problem was mongorestore is not updating the existing objects, it is just inserting.

Comment: Oh. Okay. It wont do that. You can only insert, so if you want data replaced from a restore then you must remove it.

Answer (score 0):

### Mongorestore is only for insert

In the [official MongoDB `mongorestore` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) under the [Behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#behavior) section the following is written (emphasis mine):

> #### Insert Only
>
> `mongorestore` can create a new database or add data to an existing database. However, **`mongorestore` performs inserts only and does not perform updates.** That is, if restoring documents to an existing database and collection and **existing documents have the same value _id field as the to-be-restored documents, `mongorestore` will not overwrite those documents**.

The same thing that [Niel Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) stated in his comment.